# invalid operation: currency.Name() == currency (mismatched types string and *config.Currency)

Tags: go

I have a function that takes in a string, and checks to see if that string is present in a list of other strings. Simple enough.

```
func (s *Foo) validateCurrency(currency string) error {
    for _, currency := range s.Config.Currencies {
        if currency.Name() == currency {
            return nil
        }
    }
    return ErrCurrencyNotFound
}
```

This is the `Currency` struct:

```
type Currency struct {
    name    string
    // ...
}

func (c *Currency) Name() string {
    return c.name
}
```

Yet I seem to be getting this error:

> invalid operation: currency.Name() == currency (mismatched types
>   string and *config.Currency)

Why on earth is the Go compiler yelling at me? I don't get it... both are strings. `currency.Name()` returns a string. Why does the error say it returns a `*config.Currency`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're shadowing `currency` in the for loop. Look at this code for a simpler example: https://play.golang.org/p/UFmwqQ4JZtG

First assignment to `currency` -> `func (s *Foo) validateCurrency(currency string) error {`

Second assignment which shadows the first: -> `for _, currency := range s.Config.Currencies {`

Change one of those variable names for a fix.

Comment: Facepalm. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` loop defines a variable named `currency` of type `Currency`. Your function has a parameter also named `currency`, but of type `string`. This causes `currency` inside the `for` loop to see the value of the `currency` of type `Currency` as defined in the loop instead of the function's parameter.

In short, you have two variables named `currency`, but can only access the one most recently defined.

To fix this, you should rename one of your `currency` variables to something else.

Comment: Thanks. IDE didn't highlight this, forgot I had named it that twice.